# AJAX-запрос к JSON-файлу

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Есть json-файл с массивом. Мне нужно получить этот массив с помощью ajax-запроса. Я хотел бы этот массив занести в отдельную переменную, чтобы она была в глобальной области видимости, и я её мог распарсить в js-объект. Как это можно сделать?[image: Добавил фото с кодом, который я пробовал, но нужного результата нет.]

Comment: Попробовали, работает?

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы получите сразу распарсенные данные в глобальной `myData`, но лучше обрабатывать результат внутри второго блока `then`, иначе поймете ли вы, когда данные оказались наконец в `myData`?

```
let myData;

fetch('./data.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    myData = data;
  });
```